# How to pass multiple objects as Link params in expo-router?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, expo-router

I'm creating filters for firestore query and I have two objects I need to pass to the next screen.

```
const [property, setProperty] = useState({
    propertyType: null,
    subtype: null,
    bathrooms: null,
    bedrooms: null,
  });

  const [listing, setListing] = useState({
    foreclosure: false,
    fullyFurnished: false,
    offerType: null,
    preselling: false,
    shortTerm: false,
    priceMin: null,
    priceMax: null,
  });
```

I'm trying to pass it on the link like this (with origin as pathname to next screen):

```
<Link href={`${origin}?listing=${listing}?property=${property}`} >
```

But I'm not sure how to receive it on the next screen. Is it even possible to pass multiple objects or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why don't you use navigation hook instead of Link tags like this
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    navigation.navigate("yourPage", { listing, property } );
and you get these values on the next page from useParams hook.

Comment: You can pass an object as a param by encoding the object using JSON.stringify(). Then decode the string back into actual object by using JSON.parse(). But note that, big object may make a long url, which might cause an issue due to url-lenght-limitation.